# Not able to modify File in Intellij 2016

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

[image][image]i reinstalled intellij 2016  ,whenever i am trying to modify any file (eg java,jsp) it is showing message like file is not writable.

Can any one help me on this?
i am using existing project from Git.whenever i am creating a new project i am able to modify the file and the problem only when Github branch is showing in the below right hand side.

Comment: Can you edit those files in any editor?

Comment: Yes when ever i am trying to edit the same file in notepad i am able to do.

Comment: Were you able to save this changes?

Comment: Yes and modified changes is getting reflected in intellij as well.

Comment: Then I don't know. You can try with https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/toggling-writable-status.html or https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/changing-read-only-status-of-files.html

Comment: Tried this as well but no luck!!

Comment: Maybe you can put more details - exact message or screen shot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144478/discussion-between-ravi-sinha-and-rumid).

Comment: Added Screenshot

Comment: Check the file system permissions of your files, try creating them in a different folder.

Comment: Same file i am able to modify in notepad and in Eclipse,STS as well

Comment: @CrazyCoder Can you please provide more info to resolve this issue?

Comment: Make a short video of the problem showing the full IDE window, the folders where the files reside, status bar, etc.

Comment: Hi @CrazyCoder ,I added the complete screen shot now .Can you please help me now?

Comment: It looks like you are trying to edit .java file inside the .jar. It's not possible. Use View | Select In | Project, IDE will navigate you to the file location. If it's inside the jar, you can't edit it. Open the file from the Source root of the Java module instead or unpack the jar into one of the source roots. Also make sure this directory is not added as a library somewhere, since editing of library files is disabled by design. Double check your [module dependencies](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2017.1/working-with-module-dependencies.html). Never add source roots to the libraries.

Comment: Hi @CrazyCoder This is not inside jar .This is in my sub-module and  i created a package and there java file.And file name is same whic is reflecting there but not able to modify.

Comment: Then it's added as a root to some library, remove the root from the library.

Comment: The same project structure i am using previously and  i was able to modify the files.i formatted my system and reinstalled Intellij and facing this problem,with the same project structure i am able to modify the same in class in different system.and same file i am able to edit in notepad and eclipse.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144576/discussion-between-ravi-sinha-and-crazycoder).

Comment: Hi ,now i have some more info when ever i am adding Hybris plugin and selecting while importing project  i am facing this issue (Unable to modify) ,but without hybris plugin same file i am able to modify.Can you please suggest now?

Answer (score 3):

I faced the same issue and found the solution: In your hybris integration settings uncheck `Default value for Import OOTB modules in read-only mode` check box close your project and re-import it.

During import you have a dialog showing you some hybris integration settings. There you can find a `Import OOTB modules in read-only mode` check box which now should be disabled. Leave it disabled and continue your import.

After re-importing your project all hybris files should be writable.

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly the problem